# Make text move away from top left corner of page

Tags: html, css

I am using

```html
<div class="sidebar_menu">
  <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
  <center>
    <a href="index.html">
      <h1 class="boxed_item">ADAM <span class="logo_bold">MILLINGTON</span>
      </h1>
    </a>
    <h2 class="logo_title"> 13 Year Old Web Developer</h2>
  </center>

  <ul class="navigation_selection">
    <li class="navigation_item">PROFILE</li>
    <a href="projects.html">
      <li class="navigation_item">PROJECTS</li>
    </a>
    <a href="https://github.com/Malefis">
      <li class="navigation_item">GITHUB <img class="github" src="css/assets/github.png" alt="Github image" width="20px" height="20px"></li>
    </a>
  </ul>
</div>
<h1> Hello World </h1>
```

I am trying to add text to my website in the center, I have tried adding margin-left to the h1 element but there is an area of space on the top

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pQuk.png)

My site is at malefis.github.io/portfolio or github.com/malefis/portfolio

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, could you explore more? Also, add your css as well.

Comment: Give a link to the site, give a link to a fiddle, or show all of your code or we can't really help much given just what you showed so far.

Comment: all code is at github.com/malefis/portfolio or malefis.github.io/portfolio if you want the site

Comment: Remove `margin` from `h1`.

Comment: have tried removing the margin but devtools said there in some in a place called 'less' , where may this be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this in css....for h1 element as per you described ...if its works accept the question and vote it if its not describe more about your problem

```
h1{
    position : absolute;
    top : 50%;
    left : 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

if you want at the top without space

```
 h1{
        position : absolute;
        top : 0;
        left : 50%;
    }
```

just use it

Comment: thanks , that got it dead centre in the page - If I want it to just be centered at the top then how would I do that

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the center tags and add the following to your stylesheet to remove margins and position the text.

```
h1 {
margin:0;
position : absolute;
top : 50%;
left : 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want only h1 in the top center, then just give css style text-align.

```
h1
{
  text-align:center;
}
```